# How to use two where clauses in a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query a set of data (first WHERE) and based on that result sub-query with another WHERE.
Using the following code I get

```
**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.**
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong here?

---

```
 select * from [Analytics]
    WHERE
    DateCreated >= '2014-05-01'
    AND DateCreated < '2014-06-01'
    AND Identification = 'ElementFlow'
    where exists
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Analytics]
    WHERE Location = 'x.DetailsAdvertisement' 
    OR Location = 'x.DetailsShop'
    OR Location = 'x.None'
    OR Location = 'x'
    )
```

Comment: You are selecting from the same table. Then why do you need a subquery?

Comment: Replace the second `where` with `and`.

Comment: Just a remark: Once you replace the second WHERE with AND, the exists clause is correct. It will select **all** specified records, in case the data you are looking for in the subquery exists, or **none** otherwise. This is because there is no relation from the subquery to the record in the main query. Is this desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `where exists` to `and exists` and that should be it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by removing where clause coming two times

```
select * from [Analytics]
    WHERE
    DateCreated >= '2014-05-01'
    AND DateCreated < '2014-06-01'
    AND Identification = 'ElementFlow'
    AND exists
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Analytics]
    WHERE Location = 'x.DetailsAdvertisement' 
    OR Location = 'x.DetailsShop'
    OR Location = 'x.None'
    OR Location = 'x'
    )
```

Or you try this...

```
select * from [Analytics]
        WHERE
        DateCreated >= '2014-05-01'
        AND DateCreated < '2014-06-01'
        AND Identification = 'ElementFlow'
        AND location in ('x.DetailsAdvertisement' ,'x.DetailsShop','x.None','x')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the WHERE clause twice. Replace the second WHERE with AND and it should work.

```
select * from [Analytics]
WHERE
DateCreated >= '2014-05-01'
AND DateCreated < '2014-06-01'
AND Identification = 'ElementFlow'
AND exists
(
SELECT *
FROM [Analytics]
WHERE Location = 'x.DetailsAdvertisement' 
OR Location = 'x.DetailsShop'
OR Location = 'x.None'
OR Location = 'x'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one more level, how does it sound?

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  select * from [Analytics]
  where exists
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Analytics]
    WHERE Location = 'x.DetailsAdvertisement' 
    OR Location = 'x.DetailsShop'
    OR Location = 'x.None'
    OR Location = 'x'
    )
) a
WHERE 
  DateCreated >= '2014-05-01'
  AND DateCreated < '2014-06-01'
  AND Identification = 'ElementFlow'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Analytics]
WHERE   DateCreated >= '2014-05-01' AND DateCreated < '2014-06-01'
        AND Identification = 'ElementFlow'
        AND Location IN('x.DetailsAdvertisement', 'x.DetailsShop', 'x.None', 'x')
```